# How do I get rid of duplicate elements in a cell of a dataframe column where an element can be multiple words or a single word?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I want to remove any duplicate words or group of words in the cells of two columns below and still maintain " , " between each word or group of words. Ive tried a function that uses `return (' , '.join(dict.fromkeys(text.split())))` and then apply this `function` on each column but it separates words I dont want separated and adds unneeded commas (e.g. `three four` should not be split by a comma). The solution will be applied to many more rows in `col2` and `col3`.

code:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data ={'col1':[123,123,123],'col2':['one , two , three four', 'two','three four'],
                          'col3':['many numbers , another number', 'number','another number , number']})

df0['col2'] = df0.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].transform(lambda x : ' , '.join(x))
df0['col3'] = df0.groupby(['col1'])['col3'].transform(lambda x : ' , '.join(x))
df0 = df0.drop_duplicates()

df0
```

Current output:

```
    col1    col2                                            col3
0   123     one , two , three four , two , three four       many numbers , another number , number , another number , number
```

desired output:

```
    col1    col2                        col3
0   123     one , two , three four      many numbers , another number , number
```

Comment: Does the order of the items in the strings matter in your final result?

Comment: @LeChase order does not matter as long as groups of words like `three four` are not separated.

Comment: My answer below should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.transform()` will maintain the number of rows present in your original group.  Since it seems you are using `.drop_duplicates()` on your dataframe to negate this, you are better off using `.agg()` in the first place.

From there, the solution is similar to yours, but using `set` instead of `dict` (similar, but simpler) and passing your delimiter `' , '` back to `split`.

Assuming the final order of elements does not matter, this will work:

```
delim = ' , '
df0 = df0.groupby('col1', as_index = False)[['col2', 'col3']].agg(lambda s: ' , '.join(set(delim.join(s).split(delim))))
```

Comment: thanks. I added that in to my existing code and it worked. However, are you saying it will work just as well if I replace the `.transforms()`  and `.drop_duplicates()`  with what you provided?

Comment: yes, if you use `transform` it will return the same number of rows as the original group had.  Running `drop_duplicates` after will reduce this to a single row - which is the same effect that `agg` has (`agg` will give you one row per group)